# How to get data from a nested component

Tags: vue.js, onsen-ui

I have this 3 components. One is for the Question component that consists of questions. The second is for QuestionOption for the list of choices. And the third one is my main component. How do I get the data from the QuestionOption component to the main component. Since the main component is not the parent of the QuestionOption I cannot use the $emit. Also I make use of bus but it's not working on my case. Can anyone help me on this.

Also how will I get all the chosen answers after the submission of the button? Here is my code.

**Main.vue**

```
    <div class="quiz-background">

        <question 
            v-for="(question, $indexParent) in randomQuestions"
            :question="question['doc'].question"
            :choices="question['doc']['choices']"
            :indexParent="$indexParent"
            :correctAnswer="question['doc'].correctAnswer"
        >               
        </question>

        <section style="margin:16px">
            <v-ons-button
                modifier="cta" 
                @click="submit" 
                v-show="!isDone"
            >Submit
            </v-ons-button>
        </section>

    </div>

   <script>
        submit() {

            bus.$on('choosed', function(answer) {
                console.log(answer);

            });

        }, 
   </script>
```

**Question.vue**

```
<template>

<v-ons-list>
    <v-ons-list-header>
        {{indexParent + 1}}.{{ question }}
    </v-ons-list-header>


    <question-option 
        v-for="(choice, key, $index) in choices" 
        :choice="choice" 
        :letter="key" 
        :indexParent="indexParent" 
        :index="$index"
        :correctAnswer="correctAnswer"
    >

    </question-option>


</v-ons-list>


</template>

<script>
import QuestionOption from './QuestionOption.vue';

export default {


    props: ['question', 'indexParent', 'choices', 'correctAnswer'],

    components: {
        QuestionOption
    }
}
</script>
```

**QuestionOption.vue**

```
<template>
<v-ons-list modifier="inset">
    <v-ons-list-item
        :name="'question-' + indexParent"

        :modifier="longdivider"
        :key="letter"
        tappable
    >
        <label class="left">
            <v-ons-radio    
                :name="'question-' + indexParent"
                :input-id="indexParent + '-' + index"
                :value="letter"
                :key="letter"
                v-model="chosenAnswer"
                @change="appendAnswer($event)"
            >   
            </v-ons-radio>
        </label>

        <label 
            class="center" 
            :for="indexParent + '-' + index"    
            :class="{'success' : isSuccess, 'danger' : isDanger}"       
        >
            {{ letter }} . {{ choice }}
        </label>

    </v-ons-list-item>


</v-ons-list>

</template>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue';

var bus = new Vue();

export default {


    data() {

        return {
            chosenAnswer: ''
        }
    },

    props: ['letter', 'choice','correctAnswer', 'indexParent', 'index'],

    computed: {
        isSuccess () {
            return this.chosenAnswer === this.correctAnswer;
        },
        isDanger () {

            return this.chosenAnswer !== this.correctAnswer;
        }
    },
    methods: {

        appendAnswer (event) {

            var answer = event.target.value;

            bus.$emit('choosed', answer);
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: why you say event bus doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @choasia Thanks. I updated my code. I included the submit method on the Main.vue also on the QuestionOption.vue. Am I doing the right way? Or can anyone suggest how to get the answers and put it into array.? Thanks

Comment: You didn't import event bus in `main.vue`. You can have a look at this article and give it a try. https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: @choasia I included it on my project but i just remove on my code above. var bus = new Vue().

Comment: I just made an answer to make sure you understand my idea. Please have a try to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like [the article](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) I mentioned in the comment, you can make a js file called `event-bus.js`, include code below.

```
// event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
var EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

After that, import it both in `QuestionOption.vue` and `Main.vue` like this

```
import bus from './event-bus';
```

Then try it again. The reason why your code didn't work is because you generated two Vue instances, they've got no relationship with each other, so no communication would happen.